# Using Mountebank with Node.js - Invoking methods from another class inside predicates

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, predicate, mountebank

I made a connection to a database successfully, but I don't understand how I can invoke the method that brings me the information when the conditions of any of the predicates I made are met. This is my first time virtualizing services with Mountebank together with JavaScript and NodeJs.
I hope someone can help me with this issue and the code is as follows:

```
const mbHelper = require('./mountebank-helper');
const settings = require('./settings');
const bdHelper = require('./accesoBD');

function wsCopagoService() {
    var fs = require('fs');
    
    const responseAuth = fs.readFileSync('src\\responses\\responseToken.json','utf8');
    const responseConsultarOds = fs.readFileSync('src\\responses\\responseConsultaOds.json','utf8');
    const token = JSON.parse(responseAuth)['token'];
    
    bdHelper.conexion(555438338);//<---This is the method that I want to call when the validations of some predicate are met

    const stubs = [
        {
            predicates: [
                { equals: { method: "POST" } },
                { equals: { headers: { "Content-Type": "text/plain" } } },
                { equals: { path: "/WSpago/api/token" } },
                {
                    equals: {
                        body: { 
                            "username": "CAMB_FIS",
                            "password": "Y21iRmlzRWt0UH"
                         }
                    }
                }
            ],
            responses: [
                {
                    is: {
                        statusCode: 200,
                        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json"},
                        body: responseAuth
                    }
                }
            ],
            
        },
        {
            predicates: [
                { equals: { method: "POST" } },
                {
                    and:[
                        { exists: { headers: {"Authorization": true} } },
                        {
                            equals: { headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer " + token } }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                { equals: { headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" } } },
                { equals: { path: "/WSpago/api/consultarOds" } },
                {
                    jsonpath: { selector: "$.ods" },
                    equals: { body: "555438338"}
                }
            ],
            responses: [
                {
                    is: {
                        statusCode: 200,
                        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json"},
                        body: responseConsultarOds
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ];

    const imposter = {
        port: settings.port_pago,
        protocol: 'http',
        stubs: stubs
    };

    return mbHelper.postImposter(imposter);
}

module.exports = { wsPagoService };
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.